# Animation in LongListSelector control inside a Pivot

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a Pivot control which has three PivotItems all of which are LongListSelectors, now i need to show a specific kind of animation on whatever pivot item is loaded first, i.e, the item that is dispayed to the user either while launching or while navigating back to the page. For this i have attached a loaded event to the pivot control which gives me the displayed PivotItem when control is loaded and based upon that i give the DataTemplates to the LongListSelecor inside the pivot item

```
       private async void MainPivot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sen = (Pivot)sender;

        for (int k = 0; k < sen.Items.Count; k++)
        {
            if (k == sen.SelectedIndex)
            {
                var navigatingTo = (LongListSelector)((PivotItem)((Pivot)sender).SelectedItem).Content;
                navigatingTo.ItemTemplate = Resources["AnimationDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;

            }
            else
                ((LongListSelector)((PivotItem)sen.Items[k]).Content).ItemTemplate = Resources["DefaultDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;

        }
    }
```

I have two DataTemplates one without animations

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel x:Name="Panel" Background="#f5f5f5" Width="430" Margin="2,0,0,10">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Condition, Converter={StaticResource conditionToColor}}" Height="Auto" Width="5"/>
                <StackPanel Margin="10,10,0,10" Height="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToStackPanelHeight}}" Width="330">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Text1" Text="{Binding LineOne}" Foreground="#5ac8d5" FontFamily="Lato" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToMainTextFontSize}}" Width="330" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToMainTextMargin}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Text2" Text="Hospital" Foreground="#8fa7b3" FontSize="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToSubTextFontSize}}"  Width="330" TextAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToSubTextMargin}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Text3" Text="Visited on" Foreground="#8fa7b3" FontSize="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToSubTextFontSize}}"  Width="330" TextAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToSubTextMargin}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Text4" Text="By" Foreground="#8fa7b3" FontSize="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToSubTextFontSize}}"  Width="330" TextAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToSubTextMargin}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Image Source="Assets/Images/SmallMale.png" Height="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToImageHeight}}" Margin="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToImageMargin}}" Opacity="0.25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

and another with animations

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AnimationDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel x:Name="PanelToAnimate" Background="#f5f5f5" Width="430" Margin="622,0,-622,10" Loaded="PanelToAnimate_Loaded" Unloaded="PanelToAnimate_Unloaded">
            <StackPanel.Resources>

                <Storyboard x:Name="myStackPanelboard">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.GlobalOffsetX)" Storyboard.TargetName="PanelToAnimate">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-620"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>

                <Storyboard x:Name="EndStoryBoard">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.GlobalOffsetX)" Storyboard.TargetName="PanelToAnimate">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="620"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <StackPanel.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection/>
            </StackPanel.Projection>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Condition, Converter={StaticResource conditionToColor}}" Height="Auto" Width="5"/>
                <StackPanel Margin="10,10,0,10" Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource conditionToStackPanelHeight}}" Width="330">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Text1" Text="{Binding LineOne}" Foreground="#5ac8d5" FontFamily="Lato" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="{Binding Converter={StaticResource conditionToMainTextFontSize}}" Width="330" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToMainTextMargin}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}">
                        <TextBlock.Projection>
                            <PlaneProjection/>
                        </TextBlock.Projection>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Text2" Text="Hospital" Foreground="#8fa7b3" FontSize="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToSubTextFontSize}}"  Width="330" TextAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="{Binding Converter={StaticResource conditionToSubTextMargin}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}">
                        <TextBlock.Projection>
                            <PlaneProjection/>
                        </TextBlock.Projection>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Text3" Text="Visited on" Foreground="#8fa7b3" FontSize="{Binding Converter={StaticResource conditionToSubTextFontSize}}"  Width="330" TextAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToSubTextMargin}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}">
                        <TextBlock.Projection>
                            <PlaneProjection/>
                        </TextBlock.Projection>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Text4" Text="By" Foreground="#8fa7b3" FontSize="{Binding Converter={StaticResource conditionToSubTextFontSize}}"  Width="330" TextAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource conditionToSubTextMargin}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}">
                        <TextBlock.Projection>
                            <PlaneProjection/>
                        </TextBlock.Projection>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <Image Source="Assets/Images/SmallMale.png" Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource conditionToImageHeight}}" Margin="{Binding Converter={StaticResource conditionToImageMargin}}" Opacity="0.25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The StackPanel Inside the "AnimationDataTemplate" has a loaded event in which i carry out the logic for the begining the storyboards, When the appliction starts i have get the PanelToAnimate_Loaded event for 7 times which is expected If there are say 7 items in all the longlistselectors, now if i navigate to (say i was in the 1'st PivotItem LongListSelector from there i go to 2nd PivotItem LongListSelector and navigate from there)
 and back from the next page I get the PanelToAnimate_Loaded event fired 14 times but the items inside the longlistselector are 7.

Can some One help me with this ?

Comment: Great question, too bad it never go answered :(